# Replace value in a dataframe column if value starts with a specific character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['_A1kT23', '4523', '_Currency', 'NI49O33'], 'Name': ['Example A', 'Name Xy', 'Example B', 'Test123'], 'Debt_Equity': [-65.56, 0.55, 0, 37], 'EV_Sales': [9.28, 0.53, 11.3, 45], 'Bestand': ['', '4523', 'B333', '']})
```

I would like to change the value of ISIN to "Cash" if it starts with a "_" so that I get the the new dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ISIN': ['Cash', '4523', 'Cash', 'NI49O33'], 'Name': ['Example A', 'Name Xy', 'Example B', 'Test123'], 'Debt_Equity': [-65.56, 0.55, 0, 37], 'EV_Sales': [9.28, 0.53, 11.3, 45], 'Bestand': ['', '4523', 'B333', '']})
```

I tried it by coding

```
df['ISIN'] = df['ISIN'].replace({'_':'Cash'})
```

but this works only if the value is exactly '_' and not if it starts with that specific character.
Can anyone help out please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using replace and str.startswith() in a pandas dataframe to rename values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53499792/using-replace-and-str-startswith-in-a-pandas-dataframe-to-rename-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
m=df['ISIN'].str.startswith('_')
#your condition
```

Finally:

```
df.loc[m,'ISIN']='Cash'
```

OR

via numpy's `where()` method

```
#import numpy as np
df['ISIN']=np.where(m,'Cash',df['ISIN'])
```

OR

via `mask()` method:

```
df['ISIN']=df['ISIN'].mask(m,'Cash')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `np.where` with the `startswith` condition in `list comprehension` like this:

```
df['ISIN']=np.where([i.startswith("_") for i in df['ISIN']],'cash',df['ISIN'])
```